# how to run java fileservice applet in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

I have to extend an existing applet by adding it the ability to write to a local file.
I tried the file service demo at http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs and found it was what we needed.
But I have to run it in eclipse, where I receive lots of (helpless to me) messages :

```
javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException: uninitialized
    at javax.jnlp.ServiceManager.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at graph.FileAccess.loadFileByFileService(FileAccess.java:149)
    at graph.FileAccess.loadFile(FileAccess.java:141)
    at graph.FileAccess.loadFile(FileAccess.java:117)
    at graph.FileAccess$1.actionPerformed(FileAccess.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I have already searched the web for hours and was unable to locate a solution. What is missing ?

Comment: How are you running it in Eclipse? Will [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/525316/JNLP-Web-Start/java/Eclipse-run-JNLP) be relevant?

Comment: I'va added the sample to the exixting program, and added a call to the "savefile" routine, which works : it displays the frame and the buttons as in the stand-alone sample. But when I click the "open file" or the "save file" button, I have that list of messages. I run it as "java applet" and all other parts are working fine. There is also a jnlp file coming with that sample "FileAccess.java" that looks like the one in your link. Where am I wrong ? What did I forget ?

Comment: Did you try running it as `Java Application` instead of running as `Java Applet`?

Comment: *"that list of messages."*  That means that the `javaws.jar` is not on the run-time class-path of the app. when it tries to create relevant service.  Sorry - I meant to get to this sooner, since I wrote the JNLP API examples.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : I added the path to the javaws.jar specificallly in the "classpath" tab of the "run configurations", but it still gives the same list of error messages. Can it be that there is just no good way to debug an applet in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no easy way to debug WebStart applications in Eclipse (but seems very easy with Netbeans).

A few things to try:

- [How to debug a WebStart app](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#debug)
- [Java Web Start Plugin for Eclipse (WS4E)](http://webstart.sourceforge.net/)
- [Troubleshooting Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html)

I haven't tried any of these, but I'd personally go with the first option as it's the most straightforward, even though a bit tedious as a process. I'd also experiment with WS4E to see what it can do.